# unfair to natural justice to judge the people

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "to natural justice" as "for the sake of the natural justice." Am I on the right track?

> Andrew Roberts: “If we topple Nelson, what do we do about the pyramids, built at least in part by slave labour?”
> Although it is completely illogical, ahistorical and **unfair to natural justice to judge the people** of the past by today’s morals, it is also very hard not to. If we merely judge them by the morals of their own times, that doesn’t tell us very much. If we don’t judge them morally at all, we let off the likes of Hitler and Stalin in a welter of moral relativism.

> Source:  [History Extra](https://www.historyextra.com/period/modern/historical-figures-statues-judge-morals-today/)

Comment: "natural justice" isn't the kind of "entity" that you can be ***unfair*** to (but something can certainly be described as ***inconsistent / conflicting** with natural justice*). So your cited text isn't brilliantly written, imho. But assuming you understand "natural justice", what the writer is saying is that it's ***unfair / unreasonable*** (not in accordance with natural justice) to use ***today's*** moral standards as the framework within which to judge the morality of what people did in the past.

Comment: That's sufficient to be called an answer